# Split up Table Header and Table in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I am writing a finance paper and I have some very long tables and some very long table headers.

I'd like to split them up, i.e. Header on one page and then the table following on the next. My table are done using tabular. Basic tables:

```
% Table 3
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{AAA}

Very Long Header following the Caption...

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccccc}
\hline

% Content

\hline 
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

An example would be Table 4 in the following paper (Tables are at the end of the paper): http://lerner.udel.edu/sites/default/files/WCCG/PDFs/events/Paper%2039_NAVEEN_gthink_Nov_2014.pdf

Thanks

Comment: `longtable` for example, use you must (Yoda would say so ;-))

Comment: Welcome! You cannot put it in a `table` environment, though. Just use the `longtable` environment without the float wrapper.

Comment: Ok, thanks.I tried `longtable` before but all the examples have the table information underneath the table as Notes. I need the text to go above the Table. Ill try it without the Table environment. Would the table still be included in the list of tables at the beginning of a dissertation?